# How to display all validation message in one alert

Tags: jquery

In my jquery validation I hve below, if multiple validation errors occur, I want all validations to appear in the alert at once, rather than what it is doing at more which is displaying one validation at a time in the alert. How can I display all messages in one alert?

```
    function validation() {

    var alertValidation = "";
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";

    $("input[data-type='qmark']").each(function(i) {
        var questions = $(this).attr("data-qnum");
        var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_ans_text]").text());
        var txtinput = $(this).val();
        _qid = questions;
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


        if (txtinput == '') {
            alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
        }


        if (marks < '0') {

            alertValidation += "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) + " Marks";
        }

        if (marks > '0') {

            alertValidation += "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks + " Marks Remaining";
        }

        if (alertValidation != "") {
            return false; //Stop the each loop 
        }

    });


    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}​
```

Comment: Concat all the alertValidation into one and then alert that message

Comment: @EricFrick Yeah that is the problem I am having, how do I concat the messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove this Block of code**

```
if (alertValidation != "") {
    return false; //Stop the each loop 
}
```

You are already concatenating your error messages ,  the above line of code breaks your loop when it encounters an error. So removing this should solve your problem..

Comment: Hi, what I want to do though is display an alert for one question number at a time, so if there is errors in question 1 and 3, then I want it to first show errors for question 1 only, then when that is sorted, if user validates again then show alert showing errors for question 3. If I remove this code, it shows errors in all questions at once, I just want to show all errors for one question at a time. Does that make sense>

Answer (score -1):

for each alert validation, give it a different name:

```
if (txtinput == '') {
     alertValidation1 += 'blah blah'
}
if (marks > '0') {
     alertValidation2 += 'other stuff'
}
```

then at the end for the alert, do something like:

```
alert(alertValidation1 + '\n' + alertValidation2 + '\n' ...etc)
```